# Behavior of Nullable.GetNullableType method

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

I have some C# code to detect if a type is nullable, and to get the underlying type if so:

```
...
    Log.DebugFormat("type is {0}", type.FullName);
    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("underlying type is {0}", underlyingType);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.DebugFormat("underlying type is null");
    }
...
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. Here's some output if the type is a nullable int:

```
...
    type is System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]&
    underlying type is null
...
```

I have seen similar code snippets that seem to work, so am not sure why mine is not working. One thing I notice is that the type name has an & at the end - could this be significant?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F3az5G)

Comment: @Blorgbeard But in that snippet the name doesn't have an `&` after it in the output.

Comment: Yes. So we need to see where `type` is coming from, because it's clearly not simply `typeof(int?)`.

Comment: I am going to simplify things a little, but in essence the type is coming from introspection on a method signature. Something like: ParameterInfo[] parameterInfoArray = methodInfo.GetParameters(); Type type = parameterInfoArray[0].ParameterType;

Comment: @user304582 I have an idea. I'm gonna test it, one moment.

Comment: Here is another code snippet; https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4vMfn This works as expected, so now I am more puzzled!

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to https://dotnetfiddle.net/ - very useful!

Comment: I updated the code snippet, and as Enigmativity below says, the problem occurs when the type is for an out parameter. Thank you to everyone who looked at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to replicate your issue:

```
void Main()
{
    Type type;

    type = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method").GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

    Console.WriteLine("type is {0}", type.FullName);
    Type underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("underlying type is {0}", underlyingType);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("underlying type is null");
    }
}

public void Method(out int? value)
{
    value = 42;
}
```

I get this:

```
type is System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]&
underlying type is null
```

The give away is the `&` at the end of the name. This means it's an `out` parameter. So, your type isn't just a `int?`, it's an `out int?`.

You need to call `.GetElementType()` on your type for this to work as expected.

If I do this:

```
type = this.GetType().GetMethod("Method").GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetElementType();
```

Then the output is:

```
type is System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
underlying type is System.Int32
```

Comment: This looks exactly right. I will try out GetElementType() in the hopes that this will work.

Comment: Never knew `ref` and `out` actually changed the parameter ***type***.. Interesting.

Comment: Just for clarity for future readers, "This means it's an `out` parameter" might be better worded as "This means it's an `out` or `ref` parameter" - as both append & to the end of the type.